# Why is sbt quitting when using fish?

Tags: scala, sbt, fish

I'm trying to get sbt running using the fish shell.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/fish 
java -Xmx512M -jar (dirname (status -f))/sbt-launch-0.7.4.jar "$argv"
```

When I call sbt I get the following

```
[info] Building project MyProject 1.0 against Scala 2.8.1
[info]    using MyProject with sbt 0.7.4 and Scala 2.7.7
[info] 
[info] Total session time: 1 s, completed Dec 19, 2010 4:29:46 PM
[success] Build completed successfully.
```

Then sbt quits.  Why?  Shouldn't it just wait for commands?

On a possibly related note, I'm sure I didn't used to have to do **#![shell]** on the first line when I was using bash.  What's changed?

UPDATE:
When writing the equivalent script to use bash everything works fine, sbt doesn't do a build then quit

```
#!/bin/bash
java -Xmx512M -jar `dirname $0`/sbt-launch-0.7.4.jar "$@"
```

Comment: What does `dirname (status -f)` output in a `fish` script? Is `sbt-launch-0.7.4.jar` in that directory? In general, it's not a good idea to try to run things from the same directory as the script is located. It often doesn't work. You should use a fixed location: `/path/to/sbt-launch-0.7.4.jar`. Are you running `fish` as your interactive shell? Is there some reason that such a simple script needs to be a `fish` script and not a `sh` script?

Comment: Yep, the jar is in the same dir as the script, as per directions here http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/Setup

Good points, perhaps I should just use bash (am new at this, like fish, and perhaps got carried away)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't use a shebang (`#!/usr/local/bin/fish` in your example), a script will run with the default shell on your system, which is likely `/bin/sh`.

If you run your script using `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash` does it work the way you expect it to?

There's nothing in your script that should affect how things work differently from other shells. I don't understand how your script relates to what you're doing (mostly because I'm unfamiliar with sbt). What is the name of your script? How is it called? How are you calling sbt?

Comment: The script is called 'sbt' in ~/bin, and is based on these instructions http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/Setup

Normally, when using bash, I can just call 'sbt' and it will run and present me with the sbt command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're running the shell as a script, not a shell. Fish will just run your java command and then exit.

Take the bang out of that script and make it executable and you can just run it as

/path/to/fish /path/to/script

I believe.

Comment: Without the "!" I get an error: "exec: Exec format error
fish: The file '/Users/Pengin/bin/sbt' is marked as an executable but could not be run by the operating system."

Comment: Sorry, I meant that whole line. Then "fish /script" is the same as "fish java..." and you can see what's going on. Unfortunately, I'm only on my iPad right now, so working from memory.

Comment: Same error unfortunately, but I did notice that if I keep the #! line in and remove the "$argv" then it works as expected (loosing the ability to do one-shot sbt targets that is).  

No such luck with the single "java" line though.  Can't figure out why it "could not be run by the operating system"